# MSN 'Now Playing' in my own application?

Tags: vb.net, api, msn

So my scenario is: I want my application to be able to read 'Now Playing' information from other applications that send to the MSN 'Now Playing' status.

From what I understand, these applications check for a specific handle `MsnMsgrUIManager`, and if it exists, they send the relevant song data to the application using that handle.

From searching Google, I can't find very much on MSN related api queries at all. The only things I could find were solutions to sending MSN the 'Now Playing' information that is sent from your own application - which isn't what I want.

Could anyone point me in the right direction with this?
I guess all I need to know is what dll to reference, but again.. really difficult to find anything on Google about it.

Comment: I'd really like to get an answer on this question. But it doesn't get the attention it deserves.

Answer (score 2):

Intercept the `WM_COPYDATA msg` that is sent by other application and translate it yourself. A similar example that might help you is [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120705031526/http://www.daveamenta.com/2010-07/zune-now-playing-support-for-digsby-and-winamp-compatible-nowplaying-software/)

It is in c++ but it is easy to work around that solution. Hope that helps

valter